# Callback из MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, mediaplayer, callback

Есть MediaPlayer и аудиозапись, которую нужно воспроизвести, в определенные моменты времени во время воспроизведения аудиозаписи мне нужно переключать слайды в ViewPager, как получить CallBack из MediaPlayer, что определенный момент времени наступил? Либо возможно посоветуете какие-то другие варианты.

Comment: а данный момент времени чем определен? сыграна половина композиции?

Comment: Есть массив в котором хранятся определенные секунды этого аудиотрека. Это может быть 2-ая, 5-ая, 12-секунда и так далее, может быть средина композиции.

Comment: тогда можно параллельно запустить поток, который на входе будет иметь время сна, при запуске потока погружать его в сон на это время, при выходе переключать картинку: runOnUiThread.viewpager.next()

Comment: @miha_dev А что делать если аудиозапись была остановлена, а потом опять возобновлена?

Comment: у класса Thread есть методы stop() и resume(), правда они deprecated. Либо создать класс наследник MediaPlayer, добавить в него Callback интерфейс и перегрузить методы start(), pause().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение, которое мне помогло:

```
  CountDownTimer timer;
  int timeStampIterator;
  int[] timeStamp = new int[5]; // метки с временем 

void play() { 
   mPlayer.start();
    timer = new CountDownTimer(mPlayer.getDuration() - mPlayer.getCurrentPosition(), 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            int timeSpends = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            if (timeSpends == timeStamp[timeStampIterator]) {
       mPager.setCurrentItem(LabelPosition.get(timeStampIterator))));
                timeStampIterator++;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }.start();
}

void pause() {
    mPlayer.pause();
    timer.cancel();
    timer = null;
}

void stop() {
    mPlayer.stop();
    timer.cancel();
    timer = null;
    timeStampIterator = 0;
}
```